# SyntaxError: untangle lib with element name 'def',

Tags: python, xml, keyword

I'm using `untangle` library to parse XML tree. But in tree, there is one element named `def`. If I try to access it's value

```
obj = untangle.parse(pathtoxml)
entry = obj.entry_list
defn = entry.def
```

It's showing `SyntaxError`.

```
  File "E:/python2/test/main.py", line 33
    defn = entry.def
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`def` is a keyword in Python, how can I access that value.

Here is sample tree

```
<entry_list version="1.0">
    <entry id="python">
        <ew>python</ew>
        <subj>ZH</subj>
        <art>
            <artref id="python"/>
            <capt>python</capt>
            <dim>75,15</dim>
        </art>
        <hw>py*thon</hw>
        <sound>
            <wav>python01.wav</wav>
            <wpr>!pI-+th@n</wpr>
        </sound>
        <pr>ˈpī-ˌthän, -thən</pr>
        <fl>noun</fl>
        <et>
            Latin, monstrous serpent killed by Apollo, from Greek
            <it>Pythōn,</it>
            from
            <it>Pythō</it>
            Delphi
        </et>
        <def>
            <date>1836</date>
            <dt>
                :any of various large constricting snakes (as a boa)
            </dt>
            <sd>especially</sd>
            <dt>
                :any of the large oviparous snakes (subfamily Pythoninae of the family Boidae) of Africa, Asia,
                Australia, and adjacent islands that include some of the largest existing snakes
            </dt>
        </def>
        <art>
            <bmp>python.bmp</bmp>
            <cap>python</cap>
        </art>
    </entry>
</entry_list>
```

Comment: According to their docs, you can access nodes by  a dot and attributes by [], so there seem not to be any other way. Unless you can cast it to a dictionary. Link: https://untangle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, I can, but Python Interpreter, doesn't seem to understand difference between it's keyword `def` or the `def` I'm trying to access here. Figured out the solution (`getattr`)

Answer (score 2):

So, I finally figured out a work-around to this.

```
defn = getattr(entry,'def')
```